# graph representing the randomization of each column in a binary matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix

Imagine the following binary image exemplified by the matrix below. This is a simplified version of the images I'll be working with:

```
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1
```

I want to construct a graph that will represent the randomness of each column. My thought is to develop a random index = the total transitions between each value in the column / by the total possible transitions. In the matrix above, each column could have a total possible of 3 transitions.

For the example above:

Column 1 would have a random index of 0% (0/3)

Column 2 would have a random index of 66.7% (2/3)

Column 3 = 100% (3/3)

Column 4 = 0% (0/3) even though they are 1's and not 0's. Doesn't matter, I just want the transitions.

Can I draw a boundary around all the 1 values and then have MATLAB sum all of the boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

Let your image be defined as

```
im = [ 0 1 0 1
       0 1 1 1
       0 0 0 1
       0 1 1 1 ];
```

The random index you want can be computed as

```
result = sum(diff(im)~=0) / (size(im,1)-1);
```

Explanation: `diff` computes the difference between consecutive elemtents down each column. The result is compared against zero (`~=0`), and all nonzero values within each row are added (with `sum`). Finally, the result is divided by the maximum number os transitions, which is the number of rows minus 1 (`size(im,1)-1`)

---

Equivalently, you could use `xor` between consecutive rows:

```
result = sum(xor(im(1:end-1,:), im(2:end,:))) / (size(im,1)-1)
```

Comment: You should accept @LuisMendo's answer so he gets the cred. :-) You can upvote his too (and mine if you want. He beat me to the right answer.)

Comment: @brechmos Users with low rep can't upvote. But you deserve the upvote, so here it goes :-)

Answer (score 2):

To calculate what you are suggesting you can just do:

```
sum( diff(A) ~= 0 )
```

The `diff(A)` will take the forward difference down the columns and the sum will count the number of non-zero changes.  So if you do this you will get:

```
ans =
     0     2     3     0
```

Comment: missed the percent, but the other answer has that in there.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Great responses.